# How to implement a website's javascript into Xamarin

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin

I am trying to make an android app for a website of a friends of mine. It's a mp3 downloading website.

I wanted to ask how I can implement the javascript it uses into the app of mine such that it returns the list of songs and download options.

Website's JS - http://mysong.ga/script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the JSON data the service returns. Do you have an example web link that would return data?

Once you have the JSON, use this website to translate it to a C# class: http://json2csharp.com/

From there you can use libraries such as RestSharp or roll your own with a JSON serializer (ServiceStack.Text, Json.NET etc). Using HttpClient or WebClient to get the response as string and then just use deserializer to convert that string to object. Very simple.

Comment: I just figured out about it. I get the name, bitrate etc and all. but the way he gets the download link is something about JS, can you check http://mysong.ga/script.js